# Bind Alpha Android

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I try bind to a ImageView Alpha property, I created a converter to set this for a boolean value. But I don't view setted value.

This is my converter

```
public class BooleanToOpacity : MvxValueConverter<bool,int>
{
    protected override int Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var boolean = value as bool?;

        if (boolean.Value == true)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 127;
        }                
    }

    protected override bool ConvertBack(int value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value > 127)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I use a Integer value because the Alpha value is 0 to 255.

This my line to binding value.

```
   local:MvxBind="alpha TwitterPost, Converter=BooleanToOpacity" />
```

And the Mvx trace me this

```
   MvxBind:Warning: 11.56 Failed to create target binding for binding alpha for TwitterPost
   [0:] MvxBind:Warning: 11.56 Failed to create target binding for binding alpha for TwitterPost
   10-21 15:54:22.280 I/mono-stdout(12096): MvxBind:Warning: 11.56 Failed to create target binding for binding alpha for TwitterPost
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no C# property available for "Alpha" in Xamarin.Android, so the Mvx framework doesn't know how to bind to it.

You could create a custom binding for this if you wanted to - something like:

```
    public class ImageViewAlphaTargetBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
    {
        public ImageViewAlphaTargetBinding (ImageView target) : base(target)
        {
        }

        protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
        {
            var imageView = (ImageView)target;
            imageView.SetMyProperty((int)value);
        }

        public override Type TargetType
        {
            get { return typeof(int); }
        }
    }
```

registered in Setup.cs with:

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories(Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
{
    registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<ImageView>(
                    "Alpha",
                    v=> new ImageViewAlphaTargetBinding (v) );
    base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
}
```

Alternatively, you could inherit from ImageView and provide a custom view that exposes an `Alpha` property.

For more on both these options, see:

- custom bindings http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n28-custom-bindings-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html
- inheriting to add properties - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/n33-animating-data-bound-text-changes.html

Comment: Hi @Stuart, I've solved the same issue with your solution, but my situation is quite strange (maybe I can help someone who read this).
If I write 'set.Bind(View).For(v => v.Alpha).To(vm => vm.IsDisabled).WithConversion<BoolAlphaMvxConverter>();' it works nicely on iOS emulator with iOS 11 and some Android device such as Nexus 5X.
But if I try to deploy the app to (for instance) an iPhone 5 with iOS10 and a Samsung A5 with Android 8, the binding stop to works and I need to create a custom binding as you show. All deploys are made in debug config. Why is there this difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:MvxBind="Alpha IsImageEnable , Converter = BoolToAlpha" />


public class BoolToAlphaValueConverter : BaseValueConverter<bool, Single>
    {
        protected override Single Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Single alphavalue;
            if (value)
            {
                alphavalue = 1.0f;
            }
            else {
                alphavalue = 0.35f;
            }
            return alphavalue;
        }

    }
```